# How to change value in firestore using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am learning to use cloud functions to change the values in firestore. I have a collection by the name users and a within it is a document which has a field by the name count. What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I change the value of count to less than 0, i.e. a negative number, an invocation is sent to cloud functions which in returns change the value of that count to 0.

How can I do this? I wrote a sample code and deployed it but it does not seem to work.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.checkCount = functions.firestore
  .document('boys/{count}')
  .onCreate((snap) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')

    const doc = snap.data()
    const count = doc.count
    console.log(`Starting to push token`)
    try{
    if(count < 0){
      admin.firestore().collection('boys').update({"count":0})}
      
    }catch(e){
      console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
    }
    return null
  })
```

This code somehow does not even send a request to the cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to respond:

> whenever I change the value of count

But your code triggers on:

```
functions.firestore
  .document('boys/{count}')
  .onCreate((snap) => {
```

Since you use `onCreate`, this code only triggers when the `boys/{count}` document is first created. If you want to [trigger on all writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document), use `onWrite`. Check the docs I linked for the exact signature.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but it think "admin.firestore().collection('boys').update({"count":0})}" this is incorrect as I am able to see in the logs. I tried finding a solution in the docs but couldn't.

Comment: There might be more problems in your code, but the one I pointed out is why your function never triggered.

Comment: I got everythimg to work. Thanks a lot.